# how to Export a document contain tables name, columns names and column description from SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, export

I created a db in sql server 2008 and I wrote for some columns description to describe them, What I want now is to find a way to export these tables design including the description for each column into a document to be able to discuss with the teams and be printed.

Comment: Previously:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887370/sql-server-extract-table-meta-data-description-fields-and-their-data-types

Answer (score 4):

I've created an open source project to create MS SQL Server database documentation.

http://jeremykdev.github.io/SqlServerDatabaseDocumentationGenerator

Comment: seams good, just downloaded it, but had this on VS http://screencast.com/t/20zmaLAD2 can you help to solve it?

Comment: The error appears to be caused by the long file path in the directory structure.  Renaming or moving the solution to a directory with a shorter full path.
See: http://bstruthers.com/weblog/2013/02/06/Cannot_evaluate_the_item_metadata_FullPath/

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to buy something like Red-Gate's [SQL Doc](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-doc/). There are a few people who have written scripts that you can find for free.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following recently as the first step of a full DB audit. I know there are additional fields in COLUMNS and TABLES.

```
    SELECT
        TABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLES.TABLE_NAME 'TABLE_NAME',
        COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME,
        COLUMNS.DATA_TYPE,
        COLUMNS.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
    FROM 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS,
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE
        COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = TABLES.TABLE_NAME
        AND TABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MySchema'
    ORDER BY
        TABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA,
        TABLES.TABLE_NAME,
        COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME
```